# $http service throw exception when downloading json file from server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

When trying to download a file from server i use $http service as following:

```
$http({url: url, method: "GET", withCredentials: true});
```

for some unkown reason **only** json files causing an exception when getting from server:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ] in JSON at position 1362
    at Object.parse (native)
    at tc (https://sharon-staging.comilion.com/app/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:14:245)
    at bc (https://sharon-staging.comilion.com/app/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:77:7)
    at https://sharon-staging.comilion.com/app/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:77:369
    at q (https://sharon-staging.comilion.com/app/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:7:322)
    at dd (https://sharon-staging.comilion.com/app/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:77:351)
    at c (https://sharon-staging.comilion.com/app/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:78:495)
    at https://sharon-staging.comilion.com/app/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:112:182
    at m.$eval (https://sharon-staging.comilion.com/app/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:126:250)
    at m.$digest (https://sharon-staging.comilion.com/app/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:123:365)
```

The json file is valid, i attached him in the question.

if it's a text file, or even the same file that i added a comment above the json, there is no exception.

If anyone have an idea why do i get this error, it will really really help :)

Thanks

**not working file:**

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "email": "D_user1@e2e.com",
      "nickName": "D_user1e2e"
    }
  ],
  "groups": [
    {
      "name": "D_BETWEEN_INSTANCES",
      "description": "GROUP OF USERS FROM ALL INSTANCES",
      "members": [
        "user6@e2e.com",
        "A_user6@e2e.com",
        "B_user6@e2e.com",
        "D_user1@e2e.com"
      ]
    },

  ]
}
```

**working file:**

```
tests
 {
  "users": [
    {
      "email": "D_user1@e2e.com",
      "nickName": "D_user1e2e"
    }
  ],
  "groups": [
    {
      "name": "D_BETWEEN_INSTANCES",
      "description": "GROUP OF USERS FROM ALL INSTANCES",
      "members": [
        "user6@e2e.com",
        "A_user6@e2e.com",
        "B_user6@e2e.com",
        "D_user1@e2e.com"
      ]
    },

  ]
}
```

Comment: you can check the error and format the json data by the tool HiJson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `,` sign from here-

```
"D_user1@e2e.com"
      ]
    },
```

like this-

```
"D_user1@e2e.com"
      ]
    }
```

Comment: thanks it worked, do you know how can i ignore the validaty of the json when i'm downloading a file?

Comment: I know in ajax, you can use type of `jsonp`, but I'm not sure how it's works in angular...